# Refresh listview so that it shows the selectedindex?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll

I have a  winforms listview with 200 items shown in a details listview.
50 items show at a time on the screen.  I would like to hit a button and have the listview show the selected index # - for example #113.

The problem I'm having is that I can select index 113 but the listview will not show 113 at the top of the scroll range.

What do I have to do to get the listview to move to the selectindex?

UPDATE1:

The answer is to use EnsureVisible :

```
populateListView();
this.listView1.Items[113].Selected = true;
this.listView1.Items[113].EnsureVisible();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try using `yourList.SelectedItem.EnsureVisible`

Use `list.TopItem = list.Item[x]` to have it scroll that item to the top (or attempt to)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: EnsureVisible guarantees that the selected item is visible in the listview but does not ensure that item is the top item.  The question seems to be asking how to not only make sure the item is visible but how to mike it appear "at the top of the scroll range". To accomplish this use the listView1.TopItem property.

Answer (score 4):

**Ensure visible will make sure the item you define is visible in the window but not necessairly the top item in the ListView.**

To make sure your selected item is the top item use the listView1.TopItem property

```
listView1.Items[113].Selected = true;
listView1.TopItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code for the result:

```
list.SelectedIndex = i;
list.ScrollIntoView(list.Items[i]);
```

Comment: WinForm `ListView` does not have `ScrollIntoView(ListViewItem x)`